# Comparing current value to all future values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have a dataframe similar to this that is ~10,000 to ~100,000 rows:

```
data = [['2000-01-01', 10], ['2000-01-02', 15], ['2000-01-03', 14], 
    ['2000-01-04', 13], ['2000-01-05', 17], ['2000-01-06', 16],
    ['2000-01-09', 19], ['2000-01-10', 20], ['2000-01-11', 18]]


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date', 'Value'])
```

Creating data as such:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 | 10 |
| 2000-01-02 | 15 |
| 2000-01-03 | 14 |
| 2000-01-04 | 13 |
| 2000-01-05 | 17 |
| 2000-01-06 | 16 |
| 2000-01-09 | 19 |
| 2000-01-10 | 20 |
| 2000-01-11 | 18 |

I want to compare each value to *all* the values ahead of it, and find the last instance where the value is equal to or lower than the current value. Output should look like this:

| Date | Value | Latest Date Equal or Below Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 | 10 | 2000-01-01 |
| 2000-01-02 | 15 | 2000-01-04 |
| 2000-01-03 | 14 | 2000-01-04 |
| 2000-01-04 | 13 | 2000-01-04 |
| 2000-01-05 | 17 | 2000-01-06 |
| 2000-01-06 | 16 | 2000-01-06 |
| 2000-01-09 | 19 | 2000-01-11 |
| 2000-01-10 | 20 | 2000-01-11 |
| 2000-01-11 | 18 | 2000-01-11 |

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.Series.expanding` with `idxmin`:

```
s = pd.Series(df["Value"].values, 
              index=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).view(int)).iloc[::-1]
s = s.expanding().apply(lambda x: (x - x.iloc[0]).idxmin())
df["Latest Date"] = pd.to_datetime(s).values[::-1]
```

Output:

```
         Date  Value Latest Date
0  2000-01-01     10  2000-01-01
1  2000-01-02     15  2000-01-04
2  2000-01-03     14  2000-01-04
3  2000-01-04     13  2000-01-04
4  2000-01-05     17  2000-01-06
5  2000-01-06     16  2000-01-06
6  2000-01-09     19  2000-01-11
7  2000-01-10     20  2000-01-11
8  2000-01-11     18  2000-01-11
```

Explain:

Comparing each element with its descendants is same as `expanding` in a reversed order. That's why I did `s.iloc[::-1]`.

Furthermore, `pandas.Series.expanding` can only handle if and only if the result of `apply` is numeric; so the set the index with `view(int)` that will be used for `idxmin`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using these collections of functions, it works well:

```
from datetimerange import DateTimeRange
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

# make datetime from timestamp, thus no timezone info is attached
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
date = datetime.fromisoformat(datestring)

# make local timezone with time.timezone
local_tz = timezone(timedelta(seconds=-time.timezone))

# attach different timezones as you wish
datestring = "2022-01-28 00:00:00"
utc_time = datetime.fromisoformat(datestring).astimezone(timezone.utc)
local_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(datestring).astimezone(local_tz)
print(utc_time.isoformat(timespec='seconds')) 
print(local_time.isoformat(timespec='seconds'))

# shift time by adding some minutes or hours
time = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_value).astimezone(local_tz)
new_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_value).astimezone(local_tz) + timedelta(minutes=30)
```

Check if time is higher or lower

```
print(time > new_time)   # it should be False
print(time < new_time)   # it should be True
```